# Trouble Updating a Database Record

Tags: php

Here is prepare update statement and I think I Have the Variable types out of whack, not sure.

```
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                                            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `Calibration_and_Inspection_Register` SET `item_type` = ?, `location` = ?, `date_last_test` = ?, `serial_number` = ?, `date_next_test` = ?, `comments` = ?
                                            WHERE `id`=?"))
                                    {
                                            $stmt->bind_param("issdsds",`$id`, `$item_type`, `$location`, `$date_last_test`, `$serial_number`, `$date_next_test`, `$comments`);
                                            $stmt->execute();
                                            $stmt->close();
                                    }
```

Comment: Do you really have backticks around your variables or did you have an issue trying to format the code? Also did you try to run it? What happened? What is the expected result?

Comment: In `bind_param` you have 8 variables, and in the query you have 7 `?`s

Comment: I've had nothing but issues with his code. Everything before this section works. the code is to update the DB when i hit submit it wont update and sends me to a blank page. If you would kie to see the rest of the caod3 here it is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062217/i-have-a-blank-page-after-submitting-a-php-mysqli-update-form

Comment: A "does this code look okay? question" belongs on the CodeReview site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is important if you are not using named parameters.  Since `id` is last parameter in the statement, it needs to be the last in the list of bound parameters as well.

Back-ticks around your parameter variables names in `bind_param()` call are also probably giving you errors.  It should look like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssdsdsi",$item_type, $location, $date_last_test, $serial_number, $date_next_test, $comments, $id);
```